# Bootstrap Jumbotron area doesn't go until footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to build a page with Bootstrap 3. I want that the yellow area below ends when the green footer starts. But, instead, when the yellow area ends, a white area starts before the footer. How I can fix this?

This is my code for the yellow area:

```
  <div class="jumbotron container-home-2" >
    <font color = "#FF8017">    

        <center>
        <h2>Responsa uma pesquisa aqui</h2>
        <form role="form">
           <div class="container">
              <div class="col-md-4">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="form-group">
              <center><br>
              <input class="from-control input-home" type="text" placeholder="Insira o seu código de            pesquisa aqui" required autofocus>
              </center>
              <center>
              <button type="submit" placeholder="Insira o seu código de pesquisa aqui" class="btn btn-default"><h4>Ir para a pesquisa</h4></button>
              </h4>
              </center>
              </form>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
              </div>
           </div>
       </form>
      </font>  
    </center>
 </div>
```

CSS for the yellow area

```
.container-home-2 {
  background-color:#FFE700; 
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

HTML for the footer:

```
<footer class="footer-base panel-footer jumbotron">
        <font color=#ffffff><center>&copy; Company 2013</center></font>
  </footer>
```

CSS for the footer

```
.footer-base {
  background-color:#005200; 
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top:150px;
  clear:both;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either remove the top margin, or set it to 0px if any other css may also be setting the margin, from .footer-base:

```
margin-top:150px;
```

And the same for the bottom margin from .container-home-2:

```
margin-bottom: 20px;
```

Those 2 margins created a 170px gap between the green and yellow areas.  Without those the two will now touch.

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mwkqu/)